# read file in php until a specified string is found

Tags: php, file, delimiter

I have a file that I wish to read in php and split into smaller files.

The file is base64encoded but each section is delimited in the file with a (unecoded) tilde followed by the original filename of the base64 encoded data followed by another tilde.

As a silly example, the file could look like :

NbAYnnBBA~file1.txt~NbAYnnBBANbAYnnBBANbAYnnBBANbAYnnBBA~file2.txt~

I don't want to use file_get_contents as the files could be huge and I don't want to hit memory limited.

Can anyone think of a way of doing it without having to use fgetc to do it a char at a time ?

There are no line breaks in the file by the way - it is one continous block.

Comment: Use `fread()` to read it in blocks of N characters. But a filename could straddle blocks, so if a block ends in the middle of a name, you'll need to read the next block to get the complete name.

Comment: Please don't downvote (not possible anyway), but have you tried [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) and looping with a `foreach`?

Comment: Hi Dave - file() won't work i'm afraid as there are no newlines in the file - @Barmar:  Good idea that - I will give it a go :)